# ERROR: "The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express" (VS 2019, 16.11.7)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, web-applications, iis-express

If the same issue was posted here 5 months ago and did not get any answers, would it even make sense to post it again?

Comment: Nothing comes easy for that kind of issues, as they involve too many files and configuration settings. Start a new project and see if it works, and then migrate useful pieces from the old project to this new one.

Comment: please post more details information about your requirement, Otherwise, it is difficult for us to troubleshoot your problem, such as what project did you create? What did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the project from scratch resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to open Visual Studio Installer and click on modify for "Visual Studio 2019", then in the Web Development, Make sure to check "Development Time IIS Support" Like the image below:

This should fix your problem.

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio was not considering launchSettings.json due to this missing feature.

Comment: For those on VS 2022 getting the same issue... this component doesn't seem to exist anymore (at least on 17.8.x). In my case, I think I tried to be too clever setting up VS as bare bones as I could. By not just accepting the Web Dev workload and picking what I needed myself, some link was obviously missing between VS and IISExpress. An upgrade fixed it for me, but a Repair should also do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .net core (or .net 5), in your .csproj file, make sure the Project property is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and not `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your startup project - when I had this issue it turns out I'd inadvertently switched it to the test project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your project from the Solution and add again. It will solve your problem.